# why when i run it ,it turns out to be 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, nonetype

```
def collatz_list(n):
 int_list = [n]
 int_index = n
 while int_index >1 :
     if int_index % 2 == 0:
         int_index = int_index / 2
         int_list = int_list.append(int_index)
     else:
         int_index = 3 * int_index  1
         int_list = int_list.append(int_index)
 return int_list
```

why when i run it ,it turns out to be `NoneType` object has no attribute `append`

Answer (score 4):

`.append()` does not return the list, it returns `None`. There's no need to assign back to `int_list` anyway, just `int_list.append(int_index)` would be fine.